# strange CSS / Javascript behavior when hovering over TEXTAREA or A objects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a strange problem in my web-app (php) that I noticed recently.
1 month ago it worked just fine.

When I hover above a certain < TEXTAREA > or over 2 buttons (add, exit),
in a DIV, the DIV gets filled with its background color, making the INPUT, TEXTAREA and 2 buttons invisible.

This DIV is practically a window with 2 inputs and an OK and exit button,
that I hide and show, as a "window" thing would be in Windows.

The moment I hover any other button in the page (so I do a mouseOver), the DIV
shows up again, and it starts working the proper way.

So the problem is when i hover on the TEXTAREA and the 2 buttons, the DIV gets gray.

thanks!

i hope it's not a Chrome bug, in Firefox it seems to work,
but again in Opera it doesn't. So strange.

Comment: could you please share the javascript associated with the add link button ie `addLink()` function

Comment: could you provide the css code as well? might be a webkit issue ...

Comment: i used an overflow:hidden CSS tag in the main DIV that wasn't working properly. That was preventing it to work as it should. Now it works perfectly!

Comment: so nothing much about it, too much CSS and JS, so I was lost. But thanks to you guys now it's fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took at look at your site in Chrome and was able to replicate your problem easily.

by using the "Element Inspector" i removed `overflow:hidden` from `.my_links_header_container` and could no longer replicate the problem.

i tested it several times by reloading the page.

on page load, the problem existed, but immediately. after i removed the `overflow:hidden`, it 100% did not occur again.

on a side note, you have an inline `style="display:block"` on your `.add_link_table`, which is not really a `table` element but a `div`. that's redundant because a `div` is a block element by nature -- perhaps it was a `table` element previously?

i also noticed several elements whose natural display was overridden by your CSS. i think part of this problem is related to flip-flopping your elements and displays.

Comment: thanks! it worked. Apparentyl overflow : hidden was behind this tricky bug. Removed it from CSS and now works like it should.

Comment: @Adrian glad to help, but i want to add that i consider calling it a "bug" misleading because it was the different handling of the CSS in different browsers that resulted in the appearance of a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a webkit issue.

This may not be a good solution, but give it a try
I am modifying you addLink method (use plain javascript  or jquery selectors as you like, Ive kept the original code as it is)

```
function addLink()
{
 var addLinkTable = $("#add_link_table");
    if(document.getElementById('add_link_table').style.display=='block')
    {
        document.getElementById('add_link_table').style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        addLinkTable.css("visibility","hidden");
        document.getElementById('add_link_table').style.display ='block';
        setTimeout(showTable,10);
        function showTable(){
           addLinkTable.css("visibility","visible");
         }
    }
    document.getElementById('link_name').focus();
}
```

Try it out with by switching visibility or opacity or height